# How I create login user control to be used in multiple pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I  want to create login user control in asp.net mvc site , to be used in multiple pages
 for the normal pages i have view , controller , model how i will handle all this stuff for this user control

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? The logic for redirecting the user to the login page? The default project that comes with ASP.NET MVC contains this already.

Comment: how i create this  logic in user control to be in the side bar of the site in multiple pages , The default project that comes with ASP.NET MVC contains default page not user control

Comment: I've added an answer which I hope/think answers your question. And welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% if(User.IsAuthenticated) { %>
  <%-- User is logged in, show them the sidebar to do with their account --%>
  <% Html.RenderPartial("Sidebar/LoggedInSidebar"); %>
<% } else { %>
  <%-- User needs to log in, show them a sidebar that asks for their credentials --%>
  <% Html.RenderPartial("Sidebar/LogInSidebar"); %>
<% }
```

- LoggedInSidebar points to `~/Views/Shared/Sidebar/LoggedInSidebar.ascx`
- LogInSidebar points to `~/Views/Shared/Sidebar/LogInSidebar.ascx`

Answer (score 0):

Silly question @Ahmed but can't you use the one that is generated when you create a new MVC project?

It's in the Shared folder called LogOnUserControl.ascx.

Comment: Silly reply @griegs because I need login control Username/password not action links